# Unable to install MySQL workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64

Tags: dpkg, mysql, dependencies

While installing mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb, getting dependency problems :

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community.
(Reading database ... 182641 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.54.0); however:
  Package libglibmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 (>= 3.22.0); however:
  Package libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7); however:
  Package libpcrecpp0v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libpython2.7 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0); however:
  Package libsigc++-2.0-0v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libtinfo5 (>= 6); however:
  Package libtinfo5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libzip4 (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libzip4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.10-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f` to install all dependencies. Also, which Ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install all of these packages listed first using apt-get, after that you can install mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64 .